# Why the performance is degraded in a basic client/server http requests after a certain number of requests?

Tags: http, go

I am learning how http test servers are implemented in Go. One of the tests I have done is a client sequentially launching http requests against the server. I notice that at a certain point the performance degrades and I am trying to understand why this is happening.

**Server:**

```golang
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "log"
        "net/http"
        "time"
)

var i int64

func testEndpoint(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Test API Endpoint")
        i++
        if i%500==0 {
                fmt.Printf("%8d ",i)
                fmt.Println(time.Now())
        }
}

func handleRequests() {
        http.HandleFunc("/testendpoint/", testEndpoint)
        log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe("192.168.1.10:10000", nil))
}

func main() {
        handleRequests()
}
```

**Client:**

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "net/http"
        "os"
        "strconv"
        "time"
)

func main() {

        var i int64 = 0

        for true {
                _, err := http.Get("http://192.168.1.10:10000/testendpoint/")
                if err != nil {
                        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "ERROR IN REQUEST " + strconv.FormatInt(i, 10))
                }

                i++
                if i%500==0 {
                        fmt.Printf("%8d ",i)
                        fmt.Println(time.Now())
                }
        }

}
```

If I run the server in one computer and the client in another, I get the following results both for client and server.

**Note how after around 14000 requests, the performance degrades drastically. Before that point, 500 requests were being processed in less than 300ms, but after that it takes more than 2 seconds.**

I am wondering why this could be happening. Any tip on why this might be happening or further ideas to test/debug are welcomed.

```
$ ./client
     500 2020-12-15 16:44:35.501204136 +0000 UTC m=+0.286423636
    1000 2020-12-15 16:44:35.795277425 +0000 UTC m=+0.580496937
    1500 2020-12-15 16:44:36.097232522 +0000 UTC m=+0.882452022
    2000 2020-12-15 16:44:36.386123508 +0000 UTC m=+1.171342996
    2500 2020-12-15 16:44:36.694897004 +0000 UTC m=+1.480116492
    3000 2020-12-15 16:44:36.965486139 +0000 UTC m=+1.750705639
    3500 2020-12-15 16:44:37.274670444 +0000 UTC m=+2.059889944
    4000 2020-12-15 16:44:37.54871805 +0000 UTC m=+2.333937706
    4500 2020-12-15 16:44:37.883014229 +0000 UTC m=+2.668233705
    5000 2020-12-15 16:44:38.154143461 +0000 UTC m=+2.939362937
    5500 2020-12-15 16:44:38.425432208 +0000 UTC m=+3.210651684
    6000 2020-12-15 16:44:38.698070384 +0000 UTC m=+3.483289872
    6500 2020-12-15 16:44:39.043044644 +0000 UTC m=+3.828264144
    7000 2020-12-15 16:44:39.316508615 +0000 UTC m=+4.101728103
    7500 2020-12-15 16:44:39.706906271 +0000 UTC m=+4.492125771
    8000 2020-12-15 16:44:39.977016014 +0000 UTC m=+4.762235550
    8500 2020-12-15 16:44:40.249749997 +0000 UTC m=+5.034969497
    9000 2020-12-15 16:44:40.519252681 +0000 UTC m=+5.304472181
    9500 2020-12-15 16:44:40.790891768 +0000 UTC m=+5.576111280
   10000 2020-12-15 16:44:41.061129286 +0000 UTC m=+5.846348774
   10500 2020-12-15 16:44:41.331537024 +0000 UTC m=+6.116756524
   11000 2020-12-15 16:44:41.6014923 +0000 UTC m=+6.386711776
   11500 2020-12-15 16:44:42.015862138 +0000 UTC m=+6.801081638
   12000 2020-12-15 16:44:42.27974172 +0000 UTC m=+7.064961220
   12500 2020-12-15 16:44:42.550598739 +0000 UTC m=+7.335818239
   13000 2020-12-15 16:44:43.042057538 +0000 UTC m=+7.827277026
   13500 2020-12-15 16:44:43.308593233 +0000 UTC m=+8.093812721
   14000 2020-12-15 16:44:43.579001342 +0000 UTC m=+8.364220842
   14500 2020-12-15 16:44:46.101204626 +0000 UTC m=+10.886424114
   15000 2020-12-15 16:44:49.326795176 +0000 UTC m=+14.112014676
   15500 2020-12-15 16:44:52.595643491 +0000 UTC m=+17.380862991
   16000 2020-12-15 16:44:55.913072093 +0000 UTC m=+20.698291593
   16500 2020-12-15 16:44:59.235625136 +0000 UTC m=+24.020844612
   17000 2020-12-15 16:45:02.587721179 +0000 UTC m=+27.372940679
   17500 2020-12-15 16:45:05.971204497 +0000 UTC m=+30.756423997
   18000 2020-12-15 16:45:09.670093598 +0000 UTC m=+34.455313158
   18500 2020-12-15 16:45:13.163007448 +0000 UTC m=+37.948226924

$ ./server
     500 2020-12-15 16:44:35.50228497 +0000 UTC m=+15.289897949
    1000 2020-12-15 16:44:35.796584274 +0000 UTC m=+15.584197229
    1500 2020-12-15 16:44:36.098598652 +0000 UTC m=+15.886211619
    2000 2020-12-15 16:44:36.387435748 +0000 UTC m=+16.175048739
    2500 2020-12-15 16:44:36.696201259 +0000 UTC m=+16.483814274
    3000 2020-12-15 16:44:36.966804096 +0000 UTC m=+16.754417099
    3500 2020-12-15 16:44:37.276015936 +0000 UTC m=+17.063628891
    4000 2020-12-15 16:44:37.549883639 +0000 UTC m=+17.337496654
    4500 2020-12-15 16:44:37.88435121 +0000 UTC m=+17.671964249
    5000 2020-12-15 16:44:38.155498249 +0000 UTC m=+17.943111216
    5500 2020-12-15 16:44:38.426771588 +0000 UTC m=+18.214384591
    6000 2020-12-15 16:44:38.699408325 +0000 UTC m=+18.487021304
    6500 2020-12-15 16:44:39.044393354 +0000 UTC m=+18.832006333
    7000 2020-12-15 16:44:39.317814954 +0000 UTC m=+19.105428077
    7500 2020-12-15 16:44:39.708233633 +0000 UTC m=+19.495846648
    8000 2020-12-15 16:44:39.978336727 +0000 UTC m=+19.765949682
    8500 2020-12-15 16:44:40.251108332 +0000 UTC m=+20.038721287
    9000 2020-12-15 16:44:40.520548483 +0000 UTC m=+20.308161450
    9500 2020-12-15 16:44:40.79225032 +0000 UTC m=+20.579863335
   10000 2020-12-15 16:44:41.062455042 +0000 UTC m=+20.850068045
   10500 2020-12-15 16:44:41.332890285 +0000 UTC m=+21.120503252
   11000 2020-12-15 16:44:41.602861006 +0000 UTC m=+21.390473985
   11500 2020-12-15 16:44:42.0171982 +0000 UTC m=+21.804811155
   12000 2020-12-15 16:44:42.281081042 +0000 UTC m=+22.068693997
   12500 2020-12-15 16:44:42.551927035 +0000 UTC m=+22.339540014
   13000 2020-12-15 16:44:43.043399317 +0000 UTC m=+22.831012404
   13500 2020-12-15 16:44:43.309902419 +0000 UTC m=+23.097515386
   14000 2020-12-15 16:44:43.580302453 +0000 UTC m=+23.367915456
   14500 2020-12-15 16:44:46.102551408 +0000 UTC m=+25.890164399
   15000 2020-12-15 16:44:49.328143306 +0000 UTC m=+29.115756321
   15500 2020-12-15 16:44:52.596990705 +0000 UTC m=+32.384603720
   16000 2020-12-15 16:44:55.914415702 +0000 UTC m=+35.702028717
   16500 2020-12-15 16:44:59.236974914 +0000 UTC m=+39.024587869
   17000 2020-12-15 16:45:02.589078535 +0000 UTC m=+42.376691562
   17500 2020-12-15 16:45:05.972513206 +0000 UTC m=+45.760126281
   18000 2020-12-15 16:45:09.671430175 +0000 UTC m=+49.459043154
   18500 2020-12-15 16:45:13.164329259 +0000 UTC m=+52.951942274
```

Comment: The server has a data race on `i`.  The client leaks response bodies. Close the response body in the client.

Comment: While only closing the response body might work in this case do to the buffering being able to consume the entire response, you should also be reading the response body if you want to re-use the connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably not closing the response body, which is exhausting memory and causing your machine to swap. Try this in the client:

```
res, err := http.Get("http://192.168.1.10:10000/testendpoint/")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "ERROR IN REQUEST " + strconv.FormatInt(i, 10))
}
res.Body.Close()
```

Comment: This does not cause the machine to swap, it is simply preventing connections from being reused, while leaving old connections open.